# width not changing div at all

Tags: html, css

Strange issue here which I can't see the problem with! I'm setting the width of the entire element using the class sale_container. But it's width is not changing at all!

**See [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6fVBA/3/embedded/result/)**

CSS:

```css
/*Sale styles*/
.add_sales input {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    color:#FFF;
}
.sales_toolbar input {
    width:30px;
}
.sale_container {
    width:500px;
    border:2px solid #FFF;
}
.sale_image {
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-size:cover;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.sale_image_container {
    border:solid #000 1px;
    float:left;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color:#353535;
}
.sale_image_container p {
    margin:10px;
}
.sales_toolbar {
    float:right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form class="add_sales" name="add_sales" action="php/process_sales.php" method="post">
    <div class="sale_container">
        <div class="sale_image_container">
            <div style="background-image:url(data/images/20140121/0/image8.jpg)" class="sale_image"></div>
            <p>KR</p>
        </div>
        <div class="sales_toolbar">
            <input type="text" readonly value="KRR" id="50_selected" /> <!-- Selected -->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

It seems to be working on the JSFiddle, but when I preview it in Chrome, it looks like this:
[image: Strangeeee]

Comment: It is changed for me: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/6fVBA/4/

Comment: Possible that additional styles are being included from an alternate CSS source. Have you tried using Inspect Element to view the div, and see if it has any unexpected styles being applied? Chrome natively has the feature built-in if you right-click any element.

Comment: It looks the same for me in both your jsfiddle you posted and Chrome (when I put it in a local html file). I even put a picture in and it displays the same in both. jblasco's suggestion may have some merit here.

Comment: Crap, yes I completely forgot that I had included another CSS file with some older styles! Put that as an answer please @jblasco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that additional styles are being included from an alternate CSS source. Have you tried using Inspect Element to view the div, and see if it has any unexpected styles being applied? Chrome natively has the feature built-in if you right-click any element.

Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Set position to absolute of sale_container to change width.

```
.sale_container{
   width: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   border: 2px solid #E97676;
}
```

Use firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) to inspect html element and css attributes.

Comment: This should be completely unnecessary.

Comment: I have got firebug, I prefer to use Chromes built in HTML editor tbf, seems better. if I inspect the "sale_container" styles in the browser editor it was it has a width of 190px. If I change it in the browser editor it does infact work fine.. :S